# Return lazy iterator that depends on data allocated within the function

Tags: iterator, rust, heap-memory, allocation, lifetime

I am new to Rust and reading *The Rust Programming Language*, and in the *Error Handling* section [there is a "case study"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#case-study-a-program-to-read-population-data) describing a program to read data from a CSV file using the `csv` and `rustc-serialize` libraries (using `getopts` for argument parsing).

The author writes a function `search` that steps through the rows of the csv file using a `csv::Reader` object and collect those entries whose 'city' field match a specified value into a vector and returns it. I've taken a slightly different approach than the author, but this should not affect my question. My (working) function looks like this:

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;

fn search<P>(data_path: P, city: &str) -> Vec<DataRow>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let file = File::open(data_path).expect("Opening file failed!");
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(file).has_headers(true);

    reader.decode()
          .map(|row| row.expect("Failed decoding row"))
          .filter(|row: &DataRow| row.city == city)
          .collect()
}
```

where the `DataRow` type is just a record,

```
#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct DataRow {
    country: String,
    city: String,
    accent_city: String,
    region: String,
    population: Option<u64>,
    latitude: Option<f64>,
    longitude: Option<f64>
}
```

Now, the author poses, as the dreaded "exercise to the reader", the problem of modifying this function to return an iterator instead of a vector (eliminating the call to `collect`). My question is: How can this be done at all, and what are the most concise and idiomatic ways of doing it?

---

A simple attempt that i think gets the type signature right is

```
fn search_iter<'a,P>(data_path: P, city: &'a str)
    -> Box<Iterator<Item=DataRow> + 'a>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let file = File::open(data_path).expect("Opening file failed!");
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(file).has_headers(true);

    Box::new(reader.decode()
                   .map(|row| row.expect("Failed decoding row"))
                   .filter(|row: &DataRow| row.city == city))
}
```

I return a trait object of type `Box<Iterator<Item=DataRow> + 'a>` so as not to have to expose the internal `Filter` type, and where the lifetime `'a` is introduced just to avoid having to make a local clone of `city`. But this fails to compile because `reader` does not live long enough; it's allocated on the stack and so is deallocated when the function returns.

I guess this means that `reader` has to be allocated on the heap (i.e. boxed) from the beginning, or somehow moved off the stack before the function ends. If I were returning a closure, this is exactly the problem that would be solved by making it a `move` closure. But I don't know how to do something similar when I'm not returning a function. I've tried defining a custom iterator type containing the needed data, but I couldn't get it to work, and it kept getting uglier and more contrived (don't make too much of this code, I'm only including it to show the general direction of my attempts):

```
fn search_iter<'a,P>(data_path: P, city: &'a str)
    -> Box<Iterator<Item=DataRow> + 'a>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    struct ResultIter<'a> {
        reader: csv::Reader<File>,
        wrapped_iterator: Option<Box<Iterator<Item=DataRow> + 'a>>
    }

    impl<'a> Iterator for ResultIter<'a> {
        type Item = DataRow;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<DataRow>
        { self.wrapped_iterator.unwrap().next() }
    }

    let file = File::open(data_path).expect("Opening file failed!");

    // Incrementally initialise
    let mut result_iter = ResultIter {
        reader: csv::Reader::from_reader(file).has_headers(true),
        wrapped_iterator: None // Uninitialised
    };
    result_iter.wrapped_iterator =
        Some(Box::new(result_iter.reader
                                 .decode()
                                 .map(|row| row.expect("Failed decoding row"))
                                 .filter(|&row: &DataRow| row.city == city)));

    Box::new(result_iter)
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774496/conflicting-lifetime-requirement-for-iterator-returned-from-function) seems to concern the same problem, but the author of the answer solves it by making the concerned data `static`, which I don't think is an alternative for this question.

I am using Rust 1.10.0, the current stable version from the Arch Linux package `rust`.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for asking a nicely-constructed question. Many frequent visitors don't show as much preparation, much less first-time askers. Kudos!

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, I tried my best to write a good first question, and it seems I got a well-qualified answer for it! Still, thanks for your stylistic corrections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### CSV 1.0

As I alluded to in the answer for older versions of the crate, the best way of solving this is for the CSV crate to have an owning iterator, which it now does: [`DeserializeRecordsIntoIter`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.2/csv/struct.DeserializeRecordsIntoIter.html)

```rust
use csv::ReaderBuilder; // 1.1.1
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.104
use std::{fs::File, path::Path};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct DataRow {
    country: String,
    city: String,
    accent_city: String,
    region: String,
    population: Option<u64>,
    latitude: Option<f64>,
    longitude: Option<f64>,
}

fn search_iter(data_path: impl AsRef<Path>, city: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = DataRow> + '_ {
    let file = File::open(data_path).expect("Opening file failed");

    ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(true)
        .from_reader(file)
        .into_deserialize::<DataRow>()
        .map(|row| row.expect("Failed decoding row"))
        .filter(move |row| row.city == city)
}
```

### Before version 1.0

The straightest path to convert the original function would be to simply [wrap the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423). However, doing so directly will lead to problems because [you cannot return an object that refers to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) and the result of `decode` refers to the `Reader`. If you could surmount that, you [cannot have an iterator return references to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/155423).

One solution is to simply re-create the `DecodedRecords` iterator for each call to your new iterator:

```rust
fn search_iter<'a, P>(data_path: P, city: &'a str) -> MyIter<'a>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let file = File::open(data_path).expect("Opening file failed!");

    MyIter {
        reader: csv::Reader::from_reader(file).has_headers(true),
        city: city,
    }
}

struct MyIter<'a> {
    reader: csv::Reader<File>,
    city: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIter<'a> {
    type Item = DataRow;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let city = self.city;

        self.reader
            .decode()
            .map(|row| row.expect("Failed decoding row"))
            .filter(|row: &DataRow| row.city == city)
            .next()
    }
}
```

This could have overhead associated with it, depending on the implementation of `decode`. Additionally, this might "rewind" back to the beginning of the input — if you substituted a `Vec` instead of a `csv::Reader`, you would see this. However, it happens to work in this case.

Beyond that, I'd normally open the file and create the `csv::Reader` outside of the function and pass in the `DecodedRecords` iterator and transform it, returning a newtype / box / type alias around the underlying iterator. I prefer this because the structure of your code mirrors the lifetimes of the objects.

I'm a little surprised that there isn't an implementation of [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) for `csv::Reader`, which would also solve the problem because there would not be any references.

See also:

- [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423)
- [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Recreating the iterator strikes me as somewhat abominable, but it certainly works and I suppose it would have been nicer if `IntoIterator` had been implemented. It looks like we were lucky that the `Reader` didn't rewind as you say (I found this counterintuitive; rewinding is the usual behaviour of iterators in my experience); otherwise the program might have had to be restructured. I'm used to writing functions more or less as black boxes that mirror my mental model of the problem-solving steps, but maybe this isn't a reasonable "zero-cost abstraction" in Rust.